# C Issue - Double-Linked List for a List of Students

Tags: c, struct, linked-list, doubly-linked-list, function-definition

So here are my troubles, I am trying to make **a double-linked list in C**.
But I can't manage to **add the students correctly**, the program keeps crashing on me.
I would like to make two functions one to add them on the head and one to add them on the tail.

*Hope someone could help me with this! Prepping for a binary tree, circled lists exam so I thought I'd start with this.
Thank you!*

'''

```
typedef struct student
{
    char *ime;
    char *prezime;
    char *brIndeksa;
    int godStudija;
    float prosek;
    struct student *next;
    struct student *prev;
}Student;

Student *NewStudent ();
void AddOnHead ( Student **p );

int main()
{
    int n, i;   printf("Broj studenata: "); scanf("%d", &n);
    
    Student *studenti = NULL;
    
    for ( i = 0; i < n; i++ )
        AddOnHead(&studenti);
        
    Print(studenti);
    PrintFloat(studenti,7.5);
         
    return 0;
}

Student *NewStudent ()
{
    Student *newStudent;
    newStudent = (Student*)malloc(sizeof(Student));
    if ( newStudent == NULL )
    {
        printf("ERROR: Greska u alokaciji memorije. \n");
        exit(1);
    }
    
    char txt[50];
    printf("PODACI: \n");
    
    printf("IME: ");
    scanf("%s", txt);
    newStudent->ime = (char*)malloc(strlen(txt)+1);
    if ( newStudent->ime == NULL )
    {
        printf("ERROR: Greska u alokaciji memorije. \n");
        exit(1);
    }
    strcpy(newStudent->ime,txt);
    
    printf("PREZIME: ");
    scanf("%s", txt);
    newStudent->prezime = (char*)malloc(strlen(txt)+1);
    if ( newStudent->prezime == NULL )
    {
        printf("ERROR: Greska u alokaciji memorije. \n");
        exit(1);
    }
    strcpy(newStudent->prezime,txt);
    
    printf("BROJ INDEKSA: "); 
    scanf("%s", txt);
    newStudent->brIndeksa = (char*)malloc(strlen(txt)+1);
    if ( newStudent->brIndeksa == NULL )
    {
        printf("ERROR: Greska u alokaciji memorije. \n");
        exit(1);
    }
    strcpy(newStudent->brIndeksa,txt);

    printf("GODINA STUDIJA: ");
    scanf("%d", newStudent->godStudija);
    
    printf("PROSEK: ");
    scanf("%f", newStudent->prosek);
    
    newStudent->next = NULL;
    newStudent->prev = NULL;
    
    putchar('\n');
    
    return newStudent;
}

void AddOnHead ( Student **p )
{
    Student *novi = NewStudent();
    
    if ( *p == NULL )
        *p = novi;
    else
    {
        Student *tmp = *p;
        tmp->prev = novi;
        novi->next = tmp;
        tmp = novi;
    }
}
```

'''

Comment: In calls of scanf like this scanf("%d", newStudent->godStudija); you have to use a pointer like scanf("%d", &newStudent->godStudija);

Comment: In the function AddOnHead you have to write *p = novi; instead of  tmp = novi;

Comment: Oh! Thank you so much. I overlooked that bit, it works now. All the best!

Comment: Pay attention to if you have a doubly-linked list then you should declare one more structure that will contain at least two pointers: to the head node and to the tail node.

Comment: Do you mean something like this? 

```
structstudenti{
char *ime,*prezime,*br_ind;
int godina;
float prosek;
};
structlista{`
structstudenti *glava;
structlista *rep;
}; 
```

Comment: See my answer. I provided the structure definition.

Comment: In addition to the great answer by @VladfromMoscow, you may want to see an example with the suggestions implemented [doubly-linked list of integers](https://pastebin.com/E6WpPjTC)

Answer (score 1):

In these calls of scanf

```
scanf("%d", newStudent->godStudija);
```

and

```
scanf("%f", newStudent->prosek);
```

the second argument must be a pointer to an object like

```
scanf("%d", &newStudent->godStudija);
```

and

```
scanf("%f", &newStudent->prosek);
```

In the function  `AddOnHead` instead of this statement

```
tmp = novi;
```

you have to write

```
*p = novi;
```

The function could be defined simpler. For example

```
void AddOnHead ( Student **p )
{
    Student *novi = NewStudent();
    
    novi->next = *p;

    if ( *p != NULL ) ( *p )->prev = novi;

    *p = novi;
}
```

Also if you have a doubly-linked list then you should declare one more structure like for example

```
struct List
{
    struct student *head;
    struct student *tail;
};
```

In this case  the function that appends a node to the tail of the list will be effective. You will not need to traverse the whole list to get the last node.

For example

```
struct List list = { .head = NULL, .tail = NULL };
```

For such a list the function AddOnHead can look like

```
void AddOnHead( struct List *list )
{
    Student *novi = NewStudent();
    
    novi->next = list->head;

    if ( list->head != NULL )
    {
        list->head->prev = novi;
    }
    else
    {
        list->tail = novi;
    }

    list->head = novi;
}
```

And the function can be called like

```
AddOnHead( &list );
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This is ridiculously amazing. It was taking me hours to understand this.